# invalid operands of types 'const char [6]' and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator<<'

Tags: c++

I am getting the below error when I pass a result of conditional operator value to binary operator '<<'
I saw the suggestions to use parenthesis on conditional operator as it has less precedence than '<<' but it still don't work.

Error:

> error: invalid operands of types 'const char [6]' and 'const char [3]'
>   to binary 'operator<<'

code:

```
void writeToDb(char* msg, bool doUpdate, bool doCommit)
{
ostringstream inputStr;
inputStr << "DoUpdate=" << (doUpdate?"True":"False") << ", "
         << "DoCommit=" << (doCommit?"True":"False");
}
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here

Code:

```
int
Tracer::writeLog(
    const TxnId & txnId,
    string         termination,
    int            logFlagsMask,
    bool           doUpdate,
    bool           doCommit
)
{
  ostringstream inputStr;
  inputStr << "Txn=" << txnId.display() << ", Termination=" << termination << ", "
           << "LogFlagsMask=" << logFlagsMask << ", "
           << "DoUpdate=" << (doUpdate?"True":"False") << ", " // this is line 520 in my src file.
           << "DoCommit=" << (doCommit?"True":"False");
}
```

Error:

> Tracer.cc:520: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [6]' and
>   'const char [3]' to binary 'operator<<'

Comment: `book` is `bool` right ?

Comment: Please post your *actual* code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: +1. This code does not match the indicated errors.

Comment: I cant post all the code as it is my product related, The compiler shows the line number as inputStr << "DoUpdate=" ..                      If I comment the above two lines, it compiles perfect.

Comment: Then write some different code and post the errors that _that_ generates but don't post code and errors that are unrelated.

Comment: Changing the ", " to next line worked                                                                    << "DoUpdate=" << (doUpdate?"True":"False")
 << ", "                                                                               So the error and code is related

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol: you posted wrong code

Comment: Please reproduce the error in the actual code that you intend to post and then post the code. (Including all the semicolons in their correct places.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you probably have a misplaced bracket somewhere, since the the compiler is trying to do

```
("False" << ", ")
```

i.e. streaming a `char[3]` into the `char[6]`, rather than into the `ostringstream`

Comment: Are you sure it was to do with line break, rather than brackets? Rather odd behaviour -- which compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)                        Since the conditional operator has low preference I already used the bracket for conditional operator                              inputStr << "DoUpdate=" << (doUpdate?"True":"False")